# installing tableplus on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

when following the instruction on this [page](https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/10/tableplus-linux-installation.html), for ubuntu 22.04, I get this error on the last instruction:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It seems that the developers hard linked that specific version of zlib1g (which got updated in the ubuntu repositories). Maybe contact them (in addition to reporting bugs at GitHub)  at https://tableplus.com/contact ?